# What's the meaning of "Cultural wallop"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "Cultural wallop" in the following sentence

- Seldom does a nonfiction book pack the **cultural wallop** that Dee Brown’s “Bury My Heart at Wounded Knee" did in 1970.
- After all of these years, Wharton still packs a **cultural wallop**.

Comment: I know you have already have a good answer here, but I'm curious: before asking the question, did you consult a dictionary to learn what the word _wallop_ means? It's in every dictionary I can find.

Comment: @P.E.Dant yeah, I searched! I dont know why I couldnt find :D

Comment: What dictionary do you use? Note: not what _bilingual_ dictionary, but what real English dictionary? A good place to start is [**here**](http://onelook.com/?w=wallop&ls=a). A word like this probably won't be found on a translation site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, *wallop* is a synonym for *impact*. It means that something (in the case of your first example, a book) affected the culture in some profound way.

It's a rather informal way of saying it.

There's the idiom *packs a punch*, which means "have a powerful effect". In these cases, the writers have substituted *wallop* for *punch* – perhaps to give their words more of a wallop.

Incidentally, [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pack+a+punch) recognizes "packs a wallop" as an alternative wording for "packs a punch".

Comment: A more common expression in British English would be "cultural clout". https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clout Noun #2. "Clout" and "Wallop" have the same *literal*  meaning (i.e. "hit") but "cultural wallop" seems like a mixed metaphor in BrE.